# @jsonproperty not working when @xmlelement is present

Tags: json, xml, jersey-2.0

I have the following java class

```
public class Test {

      @XmlElement(name = "NAME")
      @JsonProperty(value = "myName")
      private String name;
}
```

I want my XML output to be

```
<Test> 
  <NAME>
    abc
  </NAME> 
</Test>
```

and Json output to be `{"myName": "abc"}`

But my Json is always returned as follows : `{"NAME" : "abc"}`

looks like @jsonproperty is ignored. Can someone please help ?

Comment: What is the full qualified name (class naming including package) of your JsonProperty annotation ?

Comment: its com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;